# Load balancing mechanism using springboot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, load-balancing

I am working on a `Spring Boot REST project` say `abcproject`. From this `abcproject`, I am calling another service `xyzproject`. This `xyzproject` is distributed across the cluster of nodes (5 nodes), and for this `xyzproject` there is no load balancing implemented.

So it is our duty to call `xyzproject` from `abcproject` and perform load balancing of `xyzproject`. Is there any tool to implement in `Spring Boot` or any other way to achieve this. Your advice would be of great help.

Comment: Added code formatting for ease of readability and understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If your application are based Spring boot, then I strongly recommend you use Spring cloud stack: Eureka server, Eureka client, Feign.

Communication between services is handled by Feign, and load balance will be handled automatically in client-side by Ribbon.

Reference: [Client Side Load Balancer: Ribbon](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RC1/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html),
 [Part IV. Spring Cloud OpenFeign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RC1/multi/multi__spring_cloud_openfeign.html)